# How to obfuscate only few class or a single package?

Tags: android, proguard

I would not obfuscate all my project but just the mostly key class.
how to write the proguard file to exclude all project and obfuscate only a single class or a single package ?

Comment: What is the reason to obfuscate only 1 class/package? Calls to this class/package should be obfuscated too!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the answer before downvote. You need ! before your class.

Take a look at [Proguard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/usage.html): `Keep option` part and [Android example](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) .

Example :

```
 -keeppackagenames com.vtcmobile {
    ! com.yourpackage.CategoryParser // keep package com.vtcmobile excluded class com.vtcmobile.CategoryParser
    }
```

Edit: Use

> -keeppackagenames [package_filter]
>       Specifies not to obfuscate the given package names. The optional filter is a comma-separated list of package names. Package names can
>   contain ?, *, and ** wildcards, and they can be **preceded by the !**
>   ***negator***. Only applicable when obfuscating.

Comment: this will only keep class that extend Activity and exclude one single class, my goal is to exclude ALL the project and obfuscate only one class.

Comment: keep means keep unobfuscate