# Android disable logcat I/System of command process

Tags: android, android-logcat

I use Process to run command line instruction.

When I run an instruction, application will show "I/System﹕ exec(MY_INSTRUCTIONS)" on logcat.

But because I'm developing a private SDK for other people, so I must disable the messages on logcat.

My code looks like:

```
String[] command = {"ls", "-rf"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
try {
    Process process = pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the logcat message looks like:

```
I/System﹕ exec(ls -rf @ com.mypackage.MainActivity.cli:152)
```

I know the proguard can remove all the log message, but disable "android.util.Log" message could not correctly disable this system message.

Please help me to disable this logcat message or remove the messages by proguard.

Comment: you need to remove logcat messages ?

Comment: I want to let this message no longer show on logcat anymore.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to do what you are trying to do without ProcessBuilder. You can certainly do that command with Pure Java and not need ProcessBuilder at all.

Comment: @Yepher I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MY_INSTRUCTIONS")` to do the same thing, but I got the same logs.
Could you give me another way to do this?

Comment: If your command is ("ls", "-rf") than you can use File and look through the files in the directory. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694398/1733038

Comment: @Yepher `ls -rf` is just an example to represent for my privileges SDK, I don't need to look through the files path.

Comment: You have not given any hint at what you do need to do that requires interaction at command line so I doubt anyone can help. Without any more details all I can say is your best bet is to do what you need to do in Java or native and not use Runtime commands..

Answer (score 1):

In proguard you can add these enteries

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
But if I still need to show the other information, how to use proguard to filter that?

Comment: You can read more about the [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) here

Comment: to filter proguard enteries, read the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/20413942/1061944

Comment: Sorry, I found a mistake in my last comment. This proguard setting can correctly disable other log but can not disable the system log. maybe there is an another log class must disable?

Comment: can be done with the shell command, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: How to do with the shell command? And why you didn't recommend it? Please tell me more.

Comment: shell commands come with system privileges, thats why I do not recommend it. You can read about Android security on their Developer Portal

Comment: So I can not use that, because my SDK must be complete without system privileges.

Comment: you can use it, but Not Recommended