# proguard - what is difference between - keep and keep { } statement?

Tags: android, proguard

Am fail to fully understand significance of { ---- } after  -keep, Can someone please take below example and explain the difference ?

**Statement 1**

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View ;
```

**Statement 2**

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
```

**Statement 3**

```
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View ;
```

prevents a single class from being obfuscated, while this:

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
```

prevents (in this case) specific methods from being obfuscated. When there's brackets involved, it means the statement applies to multiple items. It can also be used to keep multiple classes, or something else where you'd keep multiple of something else. You can also use it for [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406993/enable-proguard-for-only-two-packages-in-large-android-application) or and through that specific classes in packages. The entire system is flexible because of the wildcard. Basically:

```
-keep something;
```

means keep a single one, while:

```
- keep something {
    somethingElse
}
```

specifies what to keep based on the parameter. Meaning it can specify multiple to keep. (commented version of that one:)

```
- keep something {//When something
    somethingElse//keep somethingElse
    //... and more as needed
}
```

---

It's to a certain degree comparable to an if-statement. You have two different ones:

```
if(something)
     //single line for action
```

and:

```
if(something){
    //Do multiple things
}
```

essentially:

```
-keep //keep if
     public class * extends Something //the class extends something
```

and

```
-keep //if
    public class * extends Something //the class extends something
    {
        field1//keep field1
        //and whatever else is supplied
    }
```

---

And your third example:

```
-keep public keepclassmembers * extends android.view.View { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
```

is wrong. `keepclassmembers` is something you use **instead of `-keep`**. I.e.:

```
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); 
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
  public void set*(...); 
}
```

And `-keepclassmembers` keeps the class members, while `-keep` keeps the class members and classes themselves.

Comment: in this case, how keep {} is different than keepclassmembers {}, because both prevent members only. I have updated above as statement 3 ?

Comment: statement 3 was typo, thanks for correcting it. 

So my understanding is
Statement 1 - prevent class View  from being obfuscated
Statement 2 - prevent certain methods  i.e. public <init>(android.content.Context);  which are coming
between {}  from being obfuscated
Statement 3 - prevent certain methods  i.e. public <init>(android.content.Context);  which are coming
between {}  from being obfuscated

Though I understand difference between keep and keepclassmembers , in this specific case result of statement 2
and statement 3 will be same, please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @Girish yes, it'll be the same. But with `-keepclassmembers` (AFAIK and IIRC) you can't keep nested classes. So if you have a nested class, that will still be obfuscated and can't be kept with `-keepclassmembers`

Comment: does the -keep class *  also preserve the members of the lass? saw some config has these two rules together: 

-keep public class com.google.gson.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;} 

why? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613612/why-it-needs-two-proguard-rule-keep-for-same-class, Thanks!