# why it needs two proguard rule -keep for same class

Tags: proguard

In one app, saw these two in proguard rules used in same rule file.

```
-keep public class com.google.gson.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;}
```

first one has only class.
second one brackets with some more details.

why it needs two rules? isnt the first one also apply to the class members?

Answer (score 2):

The first option (`-keep public class com.google.gson.**`) will preserve the public class names in the package com.google.gson and all underlying packages but not their members.

With the second option, which is equivalent to `-keep public class com.google.gson.** { *; }` you will preserve the public class names together with their members. Commenting out the first -keep option should make no difference.

You can use the [ProGuard Playground](https://playground.proguard.com/p/0gAZvl) to see the effect of your ProGuard configuration on the classes inside your jar/apk. I created one already with these -keep options which you can open by clicking the link.

Comment: in the  ProGuard Playground, how to see the difference/effect if "Commenting out the first -keep option "?

Comment: It currently does not support versioning/diff on the class-tree. When you upload the apk/jar, you can see the green keep tags in the class-tree appear/disappear when commenting out or adding a rule.